# Parsing html to a tree

Tags: java, html, dom, jsoup

### I've got the folowing html stucture:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td>NodeData</td>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td>NodeData</td>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>NodeData</td>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td>NodeData</td>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**However it can (in some cases) also be vertical:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8">
            NodeData
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td>NodeData</td>
        <td>NodeData</td>
        <td>NodeData</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td ">
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
        <td>
            NodeData
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I'd like to turn these tables into a tree-like structure, since they always branch from a single element. What would be the easiest way to implement that? All I've managed to come up with was creating a 2d array(table representation) and iterate through it, checking for colspan in neighbouring nodes, but surely there's a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can read your html code like an xml in this mode

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(yourHtmlString));
Document doc = builder.parse(is);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("table");
if (nodeList.getLength() != 1)
    return null;
Node node = nodeList.item(0);
Element element = (Element) node;
NodeList nl = element.getElementsByTagName("tr");
...
```

I hope I have correctly understood your question

Comment: Reading it is not an issue, as I'm using JSoup to read the html, my issue was parsing the html to a tree structure

Comment: yes, but the structure wouldn't be right, would it?